# Как вызввать окно выбора приложения?

Tags: pyside6, pyqt6, python-3.10

Я делаю программу, которая при выборе файла будет брать его путь и открывать данный файл, но я хочу выбрать через какое приложение мне его открывать. На подобии 'Открыть с помощью' в Windows или 'Open with other application' в Ubuntu.

[image: Open with other application in Ubuntu]

Как я могу вызвать подбное окно используя PySide6 и открыть файл через выбранную программу.

Comment: Какие файлы вы собираетесь выбирать и открывать? Покажите что вы уже написали и еще раз попробуйте объяснить что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Я не знаю какой файл нужно открыть пользователю. Для этого мне и нужно окно выбора программы через что запускать выбранный файл